# TextBoxes won't take focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ripple

I have this very strange problem that occurs in the Ripple Emulator where a textbox won't take focus...or at least it appears to not take focus (there is no cursor blinking in it once I click into it). However, if I start typing, then click out of the textbox, the content of the textbox suddenly updates to reflect what I've typed.

This seems to have something to do with css, AngularJS and Ionic Framework combined.

I have the below HTML (this isn't reproducible in plunkr)

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content class="has-header">
        <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Date</span>
                <input type="date" ng-change="search()" ng-model="filter.date">
            </label>

            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Only Unscheduled</span>
                <ion-checkbox ng-change="search()" style="border: none"
                              ng-model="filter.onlyUnscheduled"></ion-checkbox>
            </label>

            <label class="item item-input">
                <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="clearMatches()">Clear Matches</button>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="makeTestUsersPlay()">Make Test Users Play</button>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="makeTestDate()">Make Test Date</button>
            </label>

        </div>

        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="item in dates track by $index" style="padding: 0; padding-top: 10px;">
                <form novalidate="novalidate" on-valid-submit="save(item)">
                    <div>
                        <div class="item item-divider" style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 20px">
                            {{item.description}}{{item.isCancelled ? ' (Cancelled)' : ''}}
                        </div>
                        <label class="item item-input">
                            <span class="input-label">Location</span>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="item.location" name="location">
                        </label>
                        <label class="item item-input">
                            <span class="input-label">Time</span>
                            <input type="time" ng-model="item.time" name="time">
                        </label>

                        <div class="padding">
                            <button type="submit" class="button button-energized">
                                Save
                            </button>
                            <div style="width: 75px; padding: 0" ng-click="charge(item, item.userId1)"
                                 ng-disabled="item.user1ChargeId"
                                 class="button button-energized">
                                Charge 1
                            </div>
                            <a style="width: 75px; padding: 0" ng-click="charge(item, item.userId2)"
                               ng-disabled="item.user2ChargeId"
                               class="button button-energized">
                                Charge 2
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

If I remove the button and button-positive classes from all the buttons it suddenly works as expected.

UPDATE:

Here is the source of ionic.css where all the styles can be found

http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css

If I change the button class to:

```
.button{
    min-height: inherit;
    min-width: inherit;
    padding: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
```

The problem disappears. This suggests to me a browser rendering bug having to do with the button trying to spill out of bounds or something.

Comment: Could you please share at least the css styles of the "button" and "button-positive" classes?

Comment: Which `input` or control?

Comment: Any text input. The time inputs too

Comment: Those styles are built into the ionic framework

Comment: More info is required to debug this. I have worked with ionic and this problem never came up. Although, looking at the css you have shared, I would suggest that you utilize the stable version of ionic and not the nightly versions for all your source files.

Comment: Did you post this to Ionic's github page? I'm having the exact same issue (albeit with dropdown/select) and will report a bug if you haven't already.

Comment: I haven't because I can't tell if it's an angular issue or an ionic issue. If you wouldn't mind posting it that would be great

Comment: It seems to be specific to ripple. Can't reproduce in plunkr or on device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML5 `autofocus` attribute in your html file:

```
First name: <input type="text" name="fname" autofocus>
```

Now the focus will be set on this input element after the page is loaded.

Comment: Please, try to avoid *W3Schools* links

Comment: The problem is that the textbox won't click to obtain focus, not that I can't figure out how to autofocus on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but worth an answer. Have you checked the css color attribute. It might be set to white making it invisible.